# DAX - Calculate grand total

Tags: dax

I have a data file as below

```
TOTALUNITS  TOTALRECEIPTS
55529       12806357
45472       6813097
19605       4217647
19202       2105760
17114       2568849
16053       1577361
1506        657607
```

I need to write a measure to calculate the average of TOTALUNITS. The measure should give me a result as (TOTALUNITS/SUM(TOTALUNITS))*100 as below

```
TOTALUNITS  TOTALRECEIPTS   %TOTALUNITS
55529       12806357        31.8%
45472       6813097         26.1%
19605       4217647         11.2%
19202       2105760         11.0%
17114       2568849         9.8%
16053       1577361         9.2%
1506        657607          0.9%
```

Someone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this as a measure that will sum to 100% of what you have filtered, then try this:

```
%TotalUnits = DIVIDE(
                  SUM(Receipts[TotalUnits]),
                  CALCULATE(
                      SUM(Receipts[TotalUnits]),
                      ALLSELECTED(Receipts)))
```

If you try this as a calculated column though, you'll get 100% every time. If you want to do this as a calculated column, then you'll need to remove the `SUM` from the first argument of `DIVIDE`:

```
%TotalUnits = DIVIDE(
                  Receipts[TotalUnits],
                  CALCULATE(
                      SUM(Receipts[TotalUnits]),
                      ALL(Receipts)))
```

Calculated columns are not responsive to slicers or filtering on the report page. They are computed once when the data is loaded or refreshed, but not dynamically interactive.

Comment: Is there any workaround where we can make the calculated columns dynamically interactive with filters.

Comment: No. You have to use measures for dynamic interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, and format as Percentage:

```
%TotalUnits =
DIVIDE(
SUM(Receipts[TOTALUNITS]),
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Receipts[TOTALUNITS]),
    ALL(Receipts)
))
```

Edit: Receipt is the table name

Comment: This formula is giving me 100% always. Also I have another column as Period and the data I have provided is filtered on basis of Period.

Comment: Could you try to put a Calculate() around the first SUM?

Comment: On second thought: what are you expecting when you filter on period? The percentage of compared to period or compared to total?

Comment: I resolved the issue with below formula
%TotalUnits =
DIVIDE(
CALCULATE(SUM(Receipts[TOTAL RECEIPTS - UNITS])),
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Receipts[TOTAL RECEIPTS - UNITS]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Receipts,Receipts[Period])))

Comment: Thanku for the help